# security button Azure Devops Disappeared

Tags: azure-devops

yesterday i installed Azure Devops 2019 (2020) and everything was ok.

1. i created my first collection
2. then i granded permission to my friend as collection administrator in its group

then we checked this button and grant permission to others via panel

But today security button hide for both of us (today my security button disappeared and gone )

[image: security button Azure Devops Disappeared hide gone]

Comment: Hi there, is there any updates for this issue? Does redeploy can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try deleting and redeploying the Azure DevOps server to see if there is still the question.

By the way, you can use the REST API to view the security of the collection. This REST API was not documented, and I found it using the developer console (F12 in most browsers).

```
GET https://{instance}/{collection}/_settings/security?__rt=fps&__ver=2
```